# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint caused by IN operator in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nvarchar, in-operator

Stored Proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
    @CommaSeperatedValues nvarchar(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE SomeCol_BigIntDataType IN (@CommaSeperatedValues)
```

The Value which is coming from Code is string value: "9010073,9010074"

I tried running the SP like this: exec MyProcedure '9010073,9010074'

This is giving the error 'Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint' while running the SP

If I run the select query separately, like this:

```
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE SomeCol_BigIntDataType IN (9010073,9010074)
```

Then I'm getting the expected results.

But I want to run from SP.

Comment: You should convert the CVS into rows first.

Comment: You need to have a SplitString named function that will split the string into SQL SERVER understandable string which can then be used in the IN operator. Something like 'Select part from SplitString(@Values, ',')

Comment: It would be better to use a datatype *designed* for holding multiple values, such as a table-valued parameter or even xml, rather than stuffing multiple values into a string. SQL (in common with most languages) doesn't take a single string value, observe that it happens to contain commas, and then decide to act as if you'd actually provided multiple values to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create following tabular function as SplitString in the database. When you want to select the items; use this:

```
Select Part from SplitString(@YourValues, ',')
```

Above select statement is used in your query.

```
SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE SomeCol_BigIntDataType IN (Select Part from SplitString(@CommaSeperatedValues, ','))
```

Below function is once executed in your database.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
     -- Add the parameters for the function here
     @myString varchar(500),
     @deliminator varchar(10)
)
RETURNS
@ReturnTable TABLE
(
     -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
     [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [part] [varchar](50) NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
         Declare @iSpaces int
         Declare @part varchar(50)

         --initialize spaces
         Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
         While @iSpaces > 0

         Begin
             Select @part = 
substring(@myString,0,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0))

             Insert Into @ReturnTable(part)
             Select @part

     Select @myString = 
substring(@mystring,charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)+ 
len(@deliminator),len(@myString) - charindex(' ',@myString,0))


             Select @iSpaces = charindex(@deliminator,@myString,0)
         end

         If len(@myString) > 0
             Insert Into @ReturnTable
             Select @myString

     RETURN
END
```

Comment: This is more complex and less performant than the Moden function. TVPs are even better

Answer (score 5):

Here we go. You can do this by Dynamic Query

```
DECLARE @mystring NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @UserId  NVARCHAR(max)
SET @UserId = '9010073,9010074'
SELECT @mystring = 'SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM MyTable where UserId IN('+ @UserId +')'
EXEC sp_executesql @mystring
```

Comment: Most Elegant Solution. Good Work

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a function for splitting comma-delimited strings into separate rows. Then you call the function like this:

```
SELECT  
    Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM MyTable
WHERE 
    SomeCol_BigIntDataType IN (
        SELECT CAST(Item AS BIGINT) 
        FROM dbo.[DelimitedSplitN4K](@CommaSeperatedValues, ',')
)
```

Here is the `DelimitedSplitN4K` function by Jeff Moden. For more info: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplitN4K](
    @pString NVARCHAR(4000), @pDelimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,cteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString)/2,0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)
,cteStart(N1) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(
SELECT 
    s.N1,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,4000)
FROM cteStart s
)
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
;
GO
```

---

*DISCLAIMER: Comments are removed from the function and the formatting has been modified.*